# Discord.js record MP3 of voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, discord.js, pcm

I'm trying to make a record command in my discord.js bot. My code so far is:

```
const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if(!channel) return message.channel.send('Join a VC first!');

  const connection = await channel.join();
  const receiver = connection.receiver.createStream(message.member, {
    mode: "pcm",
    end: "silence"
  });

  const writer = receiver.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./recording.pcm'));
  writer.on('finish', () => {
    channel.leave();
    message.channel.send('It went quiet, so I left...');
  });
```

That saves `recording.pcm` to my PC. If I try to open the file in windows media player or anything, it doesn't recognise the file type. I used Audacity import raw audio function, and I could hear my recording, so I know it works. However, giving a user that type of file is very inconvenient. How can I turn this `.pcm` file into a `.wav` or `.mp3` in node.js? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just convert it with [node-lame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lame)? It supports `raw` inputs in `pcm` format.

Comment: node-lame's readme.md advises against use on Windows, and I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ffmpeg` - [npm i ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg)

```js
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

try {
  var process = new ffmpeg('path/to/pcm/file');
  process.then(function (audio) {
    audio.fnExtractSoundToMP3('path/to/new/file.mp3', function (error, file) {
      if (!error) console.log('Audio File: ' + file);
    });
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);      
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

This should save the new mp3 file to the specified location.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work (no error message), in fact, if the output file (mp3) already existed, executing the code deletes the file.

Comment: This is not the solution since this it will return an error: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: @ferluis when I have time I'll update it for you - this answer is over 2 years old.